# Unable to load app preview in iTunes connect

Tags: app-store-connect

Has anyone been able to load an app preview video in iTunes connect?  I receive an error every time, saying "Your file could not be loaded.  Please try again."

Any workaround to this, that you're aware of?

Comment: I get the same issue with screenshots... Just can't upload any one.

Comment: @serg_ov I've found a solution for the screenshots: the problem is the filename of the screenshots. Just rename the files to “1.png”, “2.png” and so on.

Answer (score 101):

*I'm here to save the day.* The root of the issue is that itunesconnect does not like the format of the file saved by quicktime, or pretty much any format for that matter.

I was able to find just 1 file format that worked. You will need a free program called  [HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr/)

Use this program to convert the file you are trying to upload with the options I have highlighted in this screenshot:
[image]

(Optional) If your video has no sound, go to the audio tab in HandBrake and remove the track, like so:
[image]

Note, when you are doing multiple conversions in a row, sometimes the output size gets screwed up, keep an eye on that (it might be a bug in handbrake).

That's it! Upload the file created by HandBrake and it works! Consider donating to the developer of HandBrake for an awesome app.

Edit: Quote from comments:

> For those who are struggling (like I was) to make a video 1080p
>   (1920x1080), don't forget to go to the Picture tab and: change the
>   Anamorphic setting to "Off", change the Modulus setting to "8" and
>   last but not least change the Cropping setting to "Custom" and set the
>   Top, Bottom, Right, Left to "0" – gaskbr Aug 18

Edit 2: You have to set the audio right also, looks like Apple don't accept files without audio channels anymore. Set the codec to AAC, 44.1 (or 48 kHz), bitrate 256.

Comment: I did everything... it still not work. :( iTunesconnect site only show "Your file could not be loaded. Please try again." after long time spin...

Comment: It isn't working for me either with those parameters.

Comment: Great!! Seems like the problem I had was the FPS rate. I have exported it from AfterFX using 25 FPS

Comment: THANK YOU!  I was getting so frustrated!

Comment: Not working for me either and I think apple are getting more rude! @Robert Mao got "Please try again" - now we just get "Try again". This is just another of the 'death by a million cuts' we suffer at apple's inept hands.

Comment: The file size went from almost 200 MB to 2.4MB - fantastic!  After 15 minutes of uploading when the internet became unusable, the error I was getting was: You haven't made any changes.

Comment: Yes a lot of fun with upload here too :), intunes connect is really buggy with this upload , Safari crashed few times an so... I will try it next time with iMovie videos instead of converting...

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, a real time saver. Now, why in the blue hell does Apple allow HD size for iPhone 6 Plus and iPhone 5 but not for iPhone 6? They all have the same aspect ratio...

Comment: @PsychoDad 1)They do not have same aspect ratio, see specs here
https://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/

2)You upload videos at the native resolution for each device, so not sure what you mean about the HD size

Comment: @spybart Apple allows 1080p (HD) videos for iPhone 5, but not iPhone 6 - that is my puzzlement.

Comment: @spybart Also, the iPhone 5, 6 and 6 Plus are all 16:9 aspect ratio - http://www.iosres.com/

Comment: @PsychoDad I'm guessing you are using some video editing software and exporting as 16:9 resolution. That's where your problem is. Look at the screen resolution for each device, you will see slight aspect ratio differences (even though it wouldn't be wrong to consider them all as 16:9). You need to match your export settings to the screen resolutions of each device. Apple allows uploading at full screen resolution for each device, there is no mystery here.

Comment: @PsychoDad You need to create a video for each device - 1136x640 video for iPhone 5, 1334x750 video for iPhone 6, 1920x1080 video for iPhone 6 Plus (and switch the width with the height for Portrait videos). Those are the screen resolutions and the video will play at full screen resolution on each device.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. Please make note of the various screen sizes you'll need to submit, and I had to ensure the anamorphic was the same.

Comment: guys dont forget to make audio settings to 44.1 and 256

Comment: I've uploaded 3 videos with Screenflow. The fourth video for iphone6 plus, started the problem. Did this with handbrake, works like a charm.

Before, the video was about 5MB. After handbrake it was 7MB. My original tho was about the slow internet... busted. it was something technical (and odd, because the others videos worked well with the same configuration)

Comment: If I could, I would give you +100! Will upvote other your answers)

Comment: For those who are struggling (like I was) to make a video 1080p (1920x1080), don't forget to go to the Picture tab and: change the Anamorphic setting to "Off", change the Modulus setting to "8" and last but not least change the Cropping setting to "Custom" and set the Top, Bottom, Right, Left to "0"

Comment: RF = 0 will generate videos without the video track. I recommend using something like RF = 25, that will create excellent quality videos of small file size.

Answer (score 7):

I have confirmed that it is because of the low upstream speed of certain ADSL, I have to buy a 3G hotspot to upload my preview video.

iMovie10.0.6 can export 'App Preview.mp4' directly, no need to convert by HandBrake.

Apple has answered me that 'Please be advised that we cannot guarantee a successful delivery if you are on a slow internet connection.'.

But I think Apple should improve their upload service like Google does.

Comment: I exported my video with iMove (App Preview), Final Cut Pro (Settings from Apple Guide for App Preview), Handbrake and with Adobe Premiere, but without success. I always get the error "Your file could not be loaded. Please try again.".

My problem was my 0,5Mbit upload connection. As I used a connection with 2,5Mb there was no error anymore. Thx Apple for wasting 2 days of my time, because you cant deliver an error message stating that you need a faster connection to not time out.

Comment: I think I'm in the same boat as Art Golf and @WolfgangPürstner - there's nothing I can do realistically other than forget about uploading videos. Yeah, and thanks apple you shower of -bleep- for wasting another day!

Comment: Ugh, we just wasted almost a day on this as well, and it also turned out to be the upload speed thing. Upload on ADSL with 800kbit/s uplink failed with nondescript error dozens of times with different video export settings, but using the iPhone's 3G (about 3.5Mbit/s upload) worked first time. I'm going to file a bug report about this with Apple, I suggest everyone else do the same.

Comment: Wou I am going to try at home then, seems like sow connection here too...

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue and Handbrake wasn't helping.

Then I found this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW14

I put together my app preview video in After Effects. So when I rendered the movie out I matched the App Preview Specifications seen in the link above and my app previews finally uploaded properly.

Comment: The link's dead

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and found out that I had to strictly follow the video specifications defined here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW14

My level was set to 5.1, audio bitrate was at 192 kbps and at 48 kHz. So I could upload the video but it showed this error message. With the correct settings every thing works fine!

I think the relevant change I made was setting the level from 5.1 to 4.0.

Some specifications you might consider for H.264 videos:
- CBR between 10 and 12 Mbps.
- Max Level 4.0.
- Audio at 256 kbps AAC with 44.1 kHz.
- Max 30 fps.
- Max 500 Mb.
- Min 15 sec, max 30 sec.

Comment: Yes, the same issue 5.1 → 4.0 and it's ok.

Comment: It should also be 4x3 and not of 16:9. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Messing about with Handbrake etc. was tedious so I made an app specifically for converting videos for iTunes Connect.

[image: Preview Video Converter Screenshot]

https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/preview-video-converter/id1137451860?mt=12

Comment: This looks very useful! Thanks!!

Comment: Didn't work for me - wrong dimensions - suggest pull this app from the store and review

Comment: @Nostradamus still works for me. What dimension is it outputting that is wrong?

Answer (score 5):

**Sometimes the error has nothing to do with your video or format.**  It's THEIR server.

I had a video that uploaded fine one day and got the ERROR : "Your app video preview is in the wrong format."  I did everything I could to tweak, check, change, re-export etc etc to fix it - thinking that it was me.  It wasn't.

They have server issues and give an error when there's nothing wrong on your end.

**HOW IT WORKED FOR ME**

- Logout of iTunes Connect
- Relax
- Go to sleep
- Wake up in the morning, relogin to iTC and try again. IT WORKS!  With the exact same video file in the exact same format!!!

My steps were to upload the new video.  Once I see the play button in Safari, I played the video all the way through.  Closed that popup.  Save.  Then submit.  I did get that message that says it could take 24 hrs for video to process but I did not get the format error.

Good luck.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I guess this is the solution, because it is simply Apple. Unstable and userunfriendly as always.

Comment: No matter how silly it is, this was the solution for me too. Spent 3 days of my life for nothing. Funny thing is "Did you try turning it off an on again" did not work. It should be "Did you try turning it off, sleep the night, and on again".

Answer (score 5):

To know more precisely why a video is being rejected, open the developer console, and look at the code. Although Apple doesn't show the problem in the interface, the code reveals why a video was rejected.

In our case, it looked like this:

```
errorCodes: Array (5) 
0"MOV_H264_LEVEL_TOO_HIGH" 
1"MOV_AUDIO_IS_MISSING" 
2"MOV_AUDIO_CODEC_NOT_ACCEPTABLE" 
3"MOV_INVALID_AUDIO_FORMAT" 
4"MOV_AUDIO_TRACKS_DURATION_TOO_SHORT" 
Array Prototype 
localizedMessage: "The H264 Level is too high. Please refer to Apple's documentation for appropriate formats." 
nonLocalizedMessage: "H264 Level is too high. Please refer to Apple's documentation for appropriate levels." 
statusCode: 400 
suggestionCode: "MOV_RESAVE_LOWER_LEVEL"
```

Comment: This should be the right answer. It gives you adequate information to work with, as opposed to the UI which doesn't say much. I was able to solve my issue with this.

Answer (score 4):

Use iMovie and create an App Preview project, then export it as an App Preview video.

Comment: Tried that, exported as app preview but still gives an error

Answer (score 4):

Adding this because I finally was able to capture a video from the Simulator and convert it to properly upload on the App Store.

First, to capture the video:

```
xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo myvideo.mp4 --codec h264 --force
```

Then, to convert it:

```
 ffmpeg  -I myvideo.mp4 -vf scale=1600:1200,setsar=1:1 -c:v libx264 -crf 1 -profile:v high -level:v 4.0 -r 30 -c:a copy rescaledvideo.mp4
```

The above rescales to iPad size, makes sure the H.264 level is acceptable, and sets the frame rate to 30fps. Apple also requires an audio track.  Since the simulator doesn't have one you can add one like this:

```
 ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -I rescaledvideo.mp4 -shortest -c:v copy -c:a aac rescaledvideo+audio.mp4
```

I wrote a script here to capture and convert iOS simulator videos:
https://github.com/kkieffer/appPreview

Answer (score 2):

If you are starting with mp4 videos created by ScreenCastOmatic, these steps work almost perfect:
http://daimtech.wordpress.com/2014/09/26/how-to-create-and-submit-a-preview-video-for-app-store-apps-using-mavericks-and-ios-8/

The one missing step is the audio needs to be in stereo form. Use **ffmpeg** with `-strict 2 -ac 2` for the output file to create stereo aac, like so:

`ffmpeg -i Preview.mp4 -strict -2 -vf scale=1136:640 **-ac 2** output.mp4`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it online using this site
http://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-mp4

and set the following

vid bitrate : 10240
frame rate: 30
audio quality: 256

Comment: and do not forget 1200x900, >15 sec

Comment: Sure @djdance also not more 30 sec, and to use safari

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that my video was too short. Apparently, **a 15 second video won't do it**. So I just recorded a longer video.

I used Apple's built in screen recorder available in iOS 11.X. No video formatting needed.

Answer (score 1):

Absolute nightmare  This is what I did.

1. I [recorded the app using my device and quicktime](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-previews/)  which gave me a portrait video, then created an 'app preview project' using iMovie, and exported it as an 'app preview project'. The device I had that day was an iPhone 6.
2. The resulting dimensions from iMovie were 750 x 1334 px but iTunes Connect was asking for 1080 x 1920 px which was surprising given what the documentation from apple was saying and also that its all just supposed to work iMovie ‍♂️.
3. so then I used [this site](https://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-mov) to convert my video to a .mov file and set the screen size to 1080 x 1920 (portrait (reverse for landscape)) set the audio codec to mp3 and video to mp4 (all of this was after trial and error)
4. finally I [converted the .mov file to .MP4](https://movtomp4.online)

Finally was able to upload to iTunes connect and it worked

✌️

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue. I resolved it by exporting the original video to mp4. It didnt worked by converting with HandBrake.

Comment: I tried all the method, apple still give the same error message. sigh.

Comment: Xcode and iTunesConnect are designed to inflict death by a thousand cuts.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work with Handbrake either, but I did get it to work (finally) with Quicktime 7. I don't even know if Apple sells iTunes 7 anymore, but it has more export options than the newer version of Quicktime do. I think iMovie might give you similar export options.

I started with a Quicktime movie (mov) file recorded from my Mac in Yosemite using the iPhone as a video source.

In Quicktime 7 I went to File -> Export and chose Movie to Quicktime Movie, and used the following settings for audio and video.

[image: Quicktime 7 video settings]
[image: Quicktime 7 audio settings]

Answer (score 0):

Adding this here incase it helps someone else.

*I was also having trouble with this and didn't think the Handbrake method was required for me because I was using Adobe CC (After Effects > Adobe Media Encoder), so I was able to specifically choose all the correct settings according to the Apple Guidelines.
But in my case the issue wasn't the format, but possibly the length it took to upload / upstream bandwidth (an undocumented timeout?).*

Tried it at home with crappy Australian cable 40mb mp4 file at 60kb/s, took about 20minutes to fully upload, and kept showing that error after it, with various formats.
Switched to my office internet which uses fibre, it uploaded in 5 seconds successfully, no format change required.

Like some of the other answers here, the Apple specifications helped a lot: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW14

Answer (score 0):

A slow internet connection could be the problem.

I also got the error message "Your file could not be loaded. Please try again." while uploading the app preview video.

I could solve the problem by switching from wifi with 160 kBit/s upload to my companies internet connection with Ethernet and 12 Mbit/s upload.

Comment: Could you provide any more details or sources for your answer?

Comment: What do you want to know? I tried several times to upload the video using my wifi connection. Then I turned wifi off, connected to my companies connection via Ethernet and iTunnes Connect instantly accepted the video without complaining...

Comment: I get this message every 1st upload attempt in Safari - 2nd attempts at upload always work - the AppStoreConnect website is something like a grade school attempt at a professional website.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are issues on the iTunes Connect server and you have to wait a little bit before trying to submit again. Usually when you upload a video and then save it, you'll get this message on top of the video:

> Processing app video. This process could take up to 24 hours.

Sometimes when I save videos that I know should work, I don't get this and I get the message mentioned in the OP. Try coming back to it later and it will probably work (assuming you've followed all of Apple's guidelines).

Answer (score 0):

If you have used QuickTime to make a screen recording, try changing the frame rate to 30fps using ffmpeg:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28939013/1588248

Answer (score 0):

I try with [Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/imovie/Creating-App-Previews-with-iMovie.pdf) to create new movie.

I small tip that when you drop video to ItunesConnect and click save button together with it, don't wait. Then you have processing screen appear. Wait from here.

That's my way, hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

My solution is just to change screenshot Japanese name to English name then it works.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here are the **ScreenFlow 5** settings I used successfully to upload my app preview:

Web - High: Customized

- H.264 Video:

  - Framerate: 30fps
  - Datarate: 1200 kbits/sec
  - Profile: *Main*
  - Keyframe Rate: Automatic
- AAC Audio:

  - Sample rate: 44.1kHz
  - Datarate: 256 kbits/sec
  - Channels: Stereo

The important bit seemed to be *not* to uncheck the AAC Audio.

Answer (score 0):

Using the **unsupported file name characters** was the issue in my case – I had to remove "space bars" from my video's file name.

Answer (score 0):

I use ffmpeg to modify videos so they are accepted in iTunes connect (modify as you need):

```
# Reduce frame rate from 60 to 30
ffmpeg -y -r 30 -i input.mp4 -strict -2 output-almost.mp4
ffmpeg -y -i output-almost.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=0.5*PTS"  -strict -2 output.mp4
rm -f output-almost.mp4

# Trim video
# From second 10, take 30 seconds
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -strict -2 -ss 10 -t 30 -async 1 output.mp4

# Set codec, bitrate, etc....
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 4.0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 256k -b:v 10M  -movflags faststart -strict -2 output.mp4
```

Also, sometimes when I press "save" in iTunes connect, after I uploaded the video, I get an error. But, then I change the tab to see another screenshots size, then I go back, press save again, and... it's saved without any error (awesome Apple...)

Answer (score 0):

Some other advice:

1. Record video using a Simulator.
2. Add silent mp3 ([get here](https://github.com/anars/blank-audio/blob/master/30-seconds-of-silence.mp3)) audio track using [OnlineConverter](https://www.onlineconverter.com/add-audio-to-video)
3. Use HandBreak as described above but also remember to set the resolution as required (depends on device).