# How to upload App Preview on iTunes Connect?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I have made a video for my app and upload this App Preview onto *iTunes Connect*. However, it cannot be saved. I already used the latest Safari on OS X 10.10 and tried many times.

Anyone succeed with upload an App Preview?

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting Safari. Worked for me after 5 failed attempts with different files.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem that iTunes Connect would not save the video.

Turns out the screen recordings I made with QuickTime off of an iPad/iPhone via Lightning cable had a frame rate that was too high (~58fps). The Apple docs say that max 30fps are allowed.

I changed the framerate with ffmpeg (installed via Homebrew):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -r 30 output.mov
```

Bonus: If you want to strip the audio from the recording, add -an as a parameter.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -an -r 30 output.mov
```

Answer (score 0):

convert vidoe online using this site and upload again
http://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-mp4

and set the following

vid bitrate : 10240
frame rate: 30
audio quality: 256