# iOS app preview video not saving in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, video, app-store-connect, preview

I created a video of my iOS game using quicktime, processed it & exported it with iMovie iOS App Preview settings. Though I'm able to upload the video to iTunes Connect and successfully play it there, could select poster frame but it says " Your file could not be loaded, try again " & when I save the page, the video doesn't get saved.

I recorded in iPhone 5C at 
Resolution : 1136 × 640 @ 30fps, 
Codecs : AAC, H.264,
Duration : 0.29 seconds.

I had already followed the handbrake and other approaches mentioned here - [Unable to load app preview in iTunes connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820601/unable-to-load-app-preview-in-itunes-connect) but in vain.

Please let me know if there's any sure shot method of uploading App preview video.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I experienced this problem too and ended up by using free app called [HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr/) to re-encode my mp4 video with specs described in the [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html)

Basically I just changed these settings :

- Video Codec (FPS)  to : **H.264(x264)**
- Video Framerate (FPS) to  : **30**
- Audio Codec to : **AAC (Core Audio)**
- Audio Mixdown to : **Stereo**
- Audio Sample rate to : **44.1**
- Audio Bitrate to : **256**

UPDATED 10/09/2020: The help link provided in this answer is from the old developer website which now forwards to the home page of the current developer help website. The current link with this information is in the link below:

https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev4e413fcb8

Comment: I would like to add , just keeping FPS to 30 and duration to 30 seconds will ensure successful upload.

Comment: #Tobio, 30fps and 30 seconds duration does *not* guarantee upload, I experienced the problem because the audio track was encoded at a sample rate of 32 and bitrate of 160. The video always failed to upload until I set them to exactly 44.1 and 256, and I tried to experiment, reverted the settings, tried again, etc, until I could confirm only those audio settings allowed me to upload.

Answer (score 4):

We ended up having this problem as well and couldn't for the life of us come up with a file that would work.

As it turns out, the video was fine all along, but iTunes Connect has a very short upload time window. Uploading a 39MB file on an ADSL connection with 800kbit/s upload is apparently not good enough. (it didn't even work with a shorter, lower-quality 13MB file) It all worked fine first try via the iPhone's 3G personal hotspot with a 4Mbit/s upload speed.

Of course, that's not what the error message says. Sigh.

Comment: I tried uploading via 3G as well, perhaps even the 3G bandwidth wasn't sufficient enough at that time. If this is the case, most individual developers in countries with low bandwidth internet isn't going to upload App Preview Video to App store. I ended up publishing my app without the video. I'll confirm next time I upload the video, meanwhile I'll wait for other experiences.

Comment: I agree, the timeout is too short, ~3 minutes is ridiculous. Why do they care how fast your connection is? I've filed a bug with Apple about this: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6375033714769920 . The error message is also misleading, so I filed a bug about that too: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5821814009757696 - If you want to rule out your file being the problem, follow this guide to create a "dummy" video: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/imovie/Creating-App-Previews-with-iMovie.pdf and try uploading that.

Comment: Sigh, wish I did read this yesterday where I spent 4 hours to upload the app preview movie. I thought my settings in FCP where wrong (although I have followed Apple's guildelines) and was re-encoding the video and trying over and over again. Someone should fire the idiots that did create this upload process (without progress indicator and without specific error messages to guide you through)

Comment: Anything new on this? I'm trying to upload with 8Mbit/s ADSL but it takes about 10 minutes before ending up with nothing.

Comment: The bug I reported to Apple (19969331) was marked as a duplicate of another (19969261) which apparently is still open as of 20th July 2015. So basically right now you're still stuck uploading from a faster connection. I'd recommend filing a bug independently and mentioning one of the above numbers in your report. The more people report it, the more likely Apple is to fix it.

Comment: I did not try upload App preview video again for this app. Will try again for my next in coming months and then post the response here. Meanwhile, If the time out window scenario is confirmed by others I shall accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

convert your videos online using this site
http://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-mp4

and set the following

vid bitrate : 10240

frame rate: 30

audio quality: 256

Comment: Thanks, this has actually worked for a 2048x1536 video recorded with Quicktime in OSX 10.10. Why it accepts mp4 and not the native mov format is quite a mistery.

Comment: i think its because of above values (bitrate, frame rate ..)
; .MOV has different specs than what apple want!!
so if you converted it to .MOV but change the specs as above, it should work

Comment: I used Quicktime's default settings which is what apple recommends to use to capture the video, isn't it (last time I checked this info was a year ago), so like maybe they should refine their QuickTime recorder or something.

Comment: This worked for me, when fiddling with Handbrake did not.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -i input.mov -vf scale=886:1920 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -shortest -strict experimental -r 30 -y appstore.mp4
```

I've used in on videos recorded using QuickTime

Comment: Thank you! This is the best answer

Answer (score 1):

Tried everything explained in other answers regarding Video settings. Still did not work for me.

I just restarted Safari and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Quic tips. Try with safari. I have resolved similar.

- Recorded video from simulator.
- Edit in iMovie App Preview feature
- Upload via Chrome Error:one or more of your app previews contain unsupported or corrupted audio
- Then try with safari and its working properly

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that the clip was 14.8 sec long, which is below the required 15 sec minimum, but somehow the „uploaded clip is too short” error didn’t fire either. Making the video 1 sec longer solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This was hard to find, but the iMovie solution works best for me. Just go to File > New App Preview to create the project. It is explicitly there for app previews on App Store Connect. You can use raw recordings of your devices, imovie does the rest in terms of format.

Answer (score -1):

This is because of poor internet connection, you've to wait for a few minutes till the Save button gets highlighted, so let it process and when the save button gets highlighted save it, that's a successful upload.

Comment: pmdj's answer should be the accepted answer here as the problem is not the video but poor internet connection and that's what I also stated.