# app preview disappears after changing the poster frame

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, app-preview

*Hey guys, I have a problem with uploading my app preview. This occurs every time I try to upload the app preview. I written down the problem in systematical text.*

**What I did with the app preview:**

- Made my app preview in Imovie and compiled it in 4k resolution with a low quality.
- Seeing this article and followed the first answer: [Unable to load app preview in iTunes connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820601/unable-to-load-app-preview-in-itunes-connect)

**What works:**

- Saving the app preview in iTunes Connect.
- Processing the app preview.
- Changing the poster frame from the app preview.

**What not works:**

- Saving the app preview again after changing the poster frame.

**What happens:**

- The app preview is disappeared, and removed from iTunes Connect.
- I never get any errors like most people get.

**More information:**

- Running Safari version: 9.1.2
- Running OS X version: 10.11.6

Comment: I am also facing this issue, please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*After trying and trying it worked one time.*

**What I did:**

- In Imovie compiled the file in high resolution.
- Followed this answer: [Unable to load app preview in iTunes connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820601/unable-to-load-app-preview-in-itunes-connect)

I think it didn't work at first because my file wasn't big enough. It was first `22 MB` and now `74 MB`.